# Body of calendar entries converted from plain text to HTML using Outlook REST API

Tags: office365, exchange-server, outlook-restapi

We are using the Microsoft Outlook REST API to synchronize the calendars of users  of our ERP system with Exchange online.

Entries from our ERP system are in plain text and are provided as such to the API.

Unfortunately, since around March 14, we noticed that, when reading back those entries, the body part of some of them was converted automatically to HTML like below

```
<html><head><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Exchange Server">
<!-- converted from text -->
<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head>
<body>
<font size="2"><span style="font-size:10pt;"><div class="PlainText">&nbsp;</div></span></font>
</body>
</html>
```

The conversion seems to be done randomly as not all entries created for a user are converted, and the problem does not happen to all our users.

What can we do to prevent this and get back the original entries as plain text?

Comment: This looks more like a question to Microsoft as its Exchange Online and they can say which update they deployed which might have caused that. DId you tried to open a ticket with them?

Comment: Yes, and their answer was to contact the API Team responsible for the Outlook REST API through StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending your email, are you specifying that your ContentType is Text? Your message should look something like this:

```
                var messageFinal = {
                    "Message": {
                        "ToRecipients": $scope.message.toRecipients,
                        "CcRecipients": $scope.message.ccRecipients,
                        "BccRecipients": $scope.message.bccRecipients,
                        "Attachments": attachmentsFinal,
                        "Subject": $scope.message.subject,
                        "Body": {
                            "ContentType": "TEXT",                       
                            "Content": $scope.message.content
                        },
                        "Importance" : $scope.message.Importance
                    }
                };
```